# Rails, HAML and JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

Just started working on a Rails/HAML server that is using Bootstrap and JQuery on the front end.  All pages are generated server side (HAML) and then we use JQuery here and there to give a Web 2.0 feel when users perform actions.

We have in a few places some complex html being generated in javascript after we make an AJAX call to get data from the server.  I.E. in on case we have a table, users can perform actions on the rows of the table.  One such action is to remove a row from the table and pull in another row.  In the case of pulling in another row we get the JSON data from the server and in the AJAX success we use the JSON data to generate the new row(HTML) and animate it into the table.

My problem with this is that the table rows are rather complex and generated in two places, server(HAML), and in javascript.  Meaning that every time I want to change up the table a little (add a css class or change the way a row looks) I need to change code in two places, server and client.

This is a legacy system and I am stuck with the frameworks that I have (might be able to convince people to pull in another).  What can I do to fix this?

Thinking the best way is to have server always generate the HTML.  I.E. instead of returning JSON data when I need to add a new row, return the HTML for the new row.  That way I can use the same HAML file server side to generate the initial rows and any new rows.

This is all pretty new to me, is this the best/only way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either do what you're doing, generate the HTML on the server, use a templating engine, or create a function to generate the rows for you.

Comment: I find it *much* easier to render HTML on the server and pass it in with a `$.html()` than to render it from json.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399229/ajax-with-ruby-on-rails-simple-view-refresh/15399379#15399379 illustrates this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found is to generate haml partials server side and return.

```
haml :some_partial, :layout => false
```

Then in jquery success:

```
function(data) {
  html = $(data);
  ...
}
```